# Interactive html from server

Tags: extjs, extjs4

somewhere in my application I get a formatted html from server to be displayed to user:

```
me.myPanel().update(response.responseText);
```

Now, I want to put in this html some links (like "add comment") in every record. I get this in the server!
But how to capture this links in extjs to act like a button or so ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use a delegate for this.

```
me.myPanel.el.on('click', me._click, me.myPanel, {
    delegate: 'a.linkclass'
});
```

In the code above you would have a couple of < a > tags in the body of your panel. `delegate`  will make sure that the click only applies to your a tags with only linkclass on them.

Here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/N9MSC/

Comment: Delegate is by far the better solution here +1

Answer (score 1):

> I recommend to use the **[answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13970804/701988)** of Johan Haest

One other way would be to give unique ID's to the buttons. You can the use `Ext.get('id')` to fetch a `Ext.dom.Element` to which you can bind event like so

```
domElementRef.on('click', function() { alert('hit') })
```

You need to do this after the update is done.

Here's a **[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sran/czrt6/13/)**